# Distorted line (with non-solid linetype) ggplot on mac

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2

First time poster here. I hope I am doing it correctly. I have had the following issue for a while now and I really want to understand what is going wrong.

I am trying to plot a dashed line with ggplot.

```
x = c(1:405)
y = c(rep(0,135),seq(1:135),rep(135,135))

ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x, y),linetype = 2, size=1)
```

However, the dashed line comes out distorted. The lines are not evenly spaced. This happens both in the plot-window in R, and when I save the plot with ggsave. When I change the size of the plot-window the distortion changes, but it occurs usually around x = 100, 200 and/or 300. It is happening both in R and Rstudio. I am using a Mac have everything updated to the newest versions. When my colleague plots the same line in linux he has no issues.

Distorted dashed line

[image]

This is the sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.12.8 gtools_3.8.1      Rcpp_1.0.3        svMisc_1.1.0      cowplot_1.0.0     dplyr_0.8.3       zoo_1.8-6         car_3.0-5         carData_3.0-3    
[10] ggplot2_3.2.1     lmerTest_3.1-1    lme4_1.1-21       Matrix_1.2-18    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5    purrr_0.3.3         splines_3.6.2       haven_2.2.0         lattice_0.20-38     colorspace_1.4-1    vctrs_0.2.1         utf8_1.1.4         
 [9] rlang_0.4.2         nloptr_1.2.1        pillar_1.4.2        foreign_0.8-72      glue_1.3.1          withr_2.1.2         readxl_1.3.1        lifecycle_0.1.0    
[17] munsell_0.5.0       gtable_0.3.0        cellranger_1.1.0    zip_2.0.4           labeling_0.3        rio_0.5.16          forcats_0.4.0       curl_4.3           
[25] fansi_0.4.0         scales_1.1.0        backports_1.1.5     abind_1.4-5         farver_2.0.1        hms_0.5.2           digest_0.6.23       stringi_1.4.3      
[33] openxlsx_4.1.4      numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 grid_3.6.2          cli_2.0.0           tools_3.6.2         magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.2      tibble_2.1.3       
[41] crayon_1.3.4        pkgconfig_2.0.3     zeallot_0.1.0       MASS_7.3-51.4       assertthat_0.2.1    minqa_1.2.4         rstudioapi_0.10     R6_2.4.1           
[49] boot_1.3-23         nlme_3.1-142        compiler_3.6.2
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: The same is happening for me on Mac. Can you add your `sessionInfo()` to your question so others might know which exact R and OS configuration you have.

Comment: It seems that using `Cairographics` with `ggsave` resolves the problem for me (see [here](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3777731)) : `ggsave("plot.png", myplot, type="cairo-png")`

Comment: @Romain Thank you, that indeed fixes the issue for me as well.

Comment: Nice, I put it as an anwser then

Comment: One of the interesting vectoring problems. I personally find it better to output as pdf and then I can save the plot with any resolution I want in any file format required by any journal, without re-arranging everything anew. (caveat: Dingbats. the `useDingbats` option can be important regarding "weird vectorising" too). [e.g. here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not explain why it is happening but using `Cairographics` with `ggsave` fixes the issue (see [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-cairographics-with-ggsave/)) :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)

x = c(1:405)
y = c(rep(0,135),seq(1:135),rep(135,135))

gg <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x, y),linetype = 2, size=1)
ggsave("plot.png", gg, type="cairo-png")
```